# Shopify - custom cart attributes not showing up in note_attributes of orders API

Tags: html, api, shopify

I am trying to add a new checkbox for Authority to Leave. Followed the steps in shopify website: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/cart/get-more-information-with-cart-attributes

The checkbox shows up in the page but when calling the orders API to retrieve the transaction, the note_attributes field is always empty.

I contacted shopify support and they said the code looks okay but they can't explain why it doesn't show up in note_attributes.

Used shopify UI generator already and tried checking the shopify forums to no avail.

I've updated cart-template.liquid and added below inside the `<form> .. </form>` tags

```
<p class="cart-attribute__field">
              <input type="hidden" name="attributes[Authority To Leave]" value="No">
              <input type="checkbox" name="attributes[Authority To Leave]" value="Yes" checked>
              <label>Authority To Leave</label>
</p>
```

I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't show up in the note_attributes field. Appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: My first guess is that the page might not be set up in a way where the attribute fields are being sent to Shopify's cart endpoint, but I'd need to know more about the page structure to be sure. Can you confirm that these inputs are located inside a form that has an action="/cart"?  Can you also please confirm that page's checkout button is a proper submit button or input with name="checkout", and not a hyperlink with href="/checkout"?

Comment: One troubleshooting trick that you can use yourself is to check the raw contents of your cart by going to `https://[yourstore]/cart.js`. This will give you the raw JSON representation of your cart, which you can quickly check for the appropriate cart notes, attributes, etc.  I often have `/cart.js` open in a separate tab while debugging cart issues so that I can quickly tab over & refresh to see if the expected changes are happening. (Note: If doing this regularly, you'll definitely want a JSON-prettifying browser extension, like JSONView or JSONFormatter)

Comment: @DaveB's solution worked for me.

Comment: @shopify-apprentice did you solve the issue? I have the exact same problem. I tried DaveB's suggestion to check cart.js and in my case, no value is added to the `attributes` key... Just wanted to know if you found any solution :)